# JSON парсинг в C#

Tags: c#, json

Мне нужно получить значение balance и username, у меня возникла проблема с получением данных из массива(не могу понять, как это делать).

```html
{"success":true,"status":"generic.ok","statuses":["generic.ok"],"response":{"users":[{"num":1,"user":{"id":200291,"uuid":"9da37ea6-7267-4092-a394-beb684d6aa96","username":"Zitz"},"balance":42277378.81}]}}
```

Мой код на данный момент:

```js
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.Create($"https://api.hil.su/v2/economy/top?limit=1&currency=coins").GetResponse();
            JSON coinstopone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSON>(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
            response.Close();

            label4.Text = "Червонцев: " + coinstopone.response;
        }

        class JSON
        {
            public dynamic response { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: JObject.Parse("json").SelectToken("response.users[0].balance").ToString();

Comment: string json - ваш json 
``const string balance_ = "\"balance\"";
int len = balance_.Length;
int pos1 = json.IndexOf(balance_)+len;
int pos2 = json.IndexOf(':', pos1)+1;
int pos3 = json.IndexOf('}', pos2);
string value = json.Substring(pos2,pos3-pos2).Trim();
double balance = double.Parse(value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);``
Аналогичным образом username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае можно сделать так:

```
string result = JObject.Parse("json").SelectToken("response.users[0].balance").ToString();
```

Username вытягиваете аналогично:

```
string result = JObject.Parse("json").SelectToken("response.users[0].user.username").ToString();
```

[Подробнее тут](https://www.newtonsoft.com/)

Comment: Спасибо большое!